# Forward data from host to a simulated network node in guest

Tags: networking, debian, ipv6, forwarding, vmware-player

I want to forward some `UDP` or `TCP` packet from a program on my host OS to another program that is running on the guest OS.

```
HOST OS: Debian 9
GUEST OS: Ubuntu 14.04 on Vmware player
```

In fact there is a `simulated ipv6 network` running on the guest OS and each node in the simulated network is reachable in the guest (I can `ping6` all nodes). But i want to reach those nodes from my host OS. They aren't reachable from the host.

How can i reach them (`ping6` them or send some packets) from my Host OS?

Comment: What is "simulated ipv6 network" and how does it relate to the VMware virtual network adapters (VMnet1 etc.) ?

Comment: An IPv6 network simulated in `Cooja` simulator. It related to the guest OS with a `tun0` adapter. This is a tunnel that works with `SLIP` protocol. [This picture](https://pasteboard.co/HCjNlRw.png) shows the output of `ifconfig` command in guest OS.